# Apps script that copies a template Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an apps script that creates a new Google workbook each time a new entry is made in Column A of sheet1 of a Master workbook and renames that new workbook to the last entered data in column A of sheet1 of the Master workbook. It also pastes the URL of the newly created workbooks in Column J of sheet1 of the master workbook.
The apps script code is run by an onEdit trigger I set manually. Each time a new workbook is created, the last row that was edited gets copied (from A to J) to the newly created workbook. Every workbook both the master workbook and the newly created workbooks gets shared with a list of emails typed in Column B of Sheet 2 of the master workbook (as editors). Below is the code.

```
function myFunction() {   
  // Creating new Spreadsheet.   
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();   
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();   
  const lastRow = sh.getLastRow();   
  const values = sh.getRange(`A${lastRow}:J${lastRow}`).getValues()[0];   
  const nss = SpreadsheetApp.create(values[0]);   
  const url = nss.getUrl();   
  sh.getRange(lastRow, 10).setValue(url);   
  values[9] = url;   
  nss.appendRow(values);
  
  // Sharing Spreadsheets.   
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");   
  const emails = [...new Set(sheet2.getRange("B1:B" + sheet2.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((ar, [b]) => {
      if (b && b.includes("@")) ar.push(b);
      return ar;   
      }, []))];   
  ss.getEditors().forEach(e => ss.removeEditor(e));   
  ss.addEditors(emails);   
  nss.addEditors(emails); 
}
```

I have been trying to make the master workbook copy a template sheet (by ID), but I haven't done so successfully. I need your help on this. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You're usage of worksheet, spreadsheet and sheet are a little confusing. Can you update your post to be as accurate as possible?

Comment: Ok.I will do that right away

Comment: That looks much better! Thank you. `I have been trying to make the master sheet copy a template sheet (by ID)`. Is this a specific sheet in the Spreadsheet you would like to copy, or the entire Spreadsheet you would like to copy?

Comment: It is quite unclear when you said _"make the master workbook copy a template sheet (by ID)"_. Do you specifically want to create a template copy of your **master workbook**? Or is it the newly created workbook sheet based from the new entry? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy sheet from Master to new Spreadsheet:

```
const MasterSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

const NewSpreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.create(`New`).getId()
const NewSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(NewSpreadsheetId)

MasterSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(`TargetSheet`)
                 .copyTo(NewSpreadsheet)
                 .setName(`CopiedSheet`)
```

### Copy Spreadsheet to new Spreadsheet:

```
const MasterSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

const NewSpreadsheetId = MasterSpreadsheet.copy(`Copy of ${MasterSpreadsheet.getName()}`).getId()
const NewSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(NewSpreadsheetId)
```

Note: Copying a Spreadsheet will place the new Spreadsheet file in your Drive 'root' folder. You can however, use `DriveApp` to get the file using `NewSpreadsheetId` and move it to a specified folder.

If neither of these help, or you need further explanation, please let me know!